# Convert extension method to custom DisplayFormatAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an extension method that converts the decimal to string in a customized format

```
public static string ToForecastNumber(this decimal number)
{
    var num = Convert.ToInt64(number);

    //Ensure number has max 3 significant digits (no rounding up can happen)
    var i = (long)Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Max(0, Math.Log10(num) - 2));
    num = num / i * i;
    if (num >= 1000000000)
        return (num / 1000000000D).ToString("0.##") + "B";
    if (num >= 1000000)
        return (num / 1000000D).ToString("0.##") + "M";
    if (num >= 1000)
        return (num / 1000D).ToString("0.##") + "K";

    return num.ToString("#,0");
}
```

This returns numbers in 352K, 204M format.

I cannot use this extension method in `@Html.DisplayFor` because it requires a property.
So to use this, I will have to put `@Model.Amount.ToForecastNumber()` instead which I feel is not the right thing to do.

Is there a way I can extend the `DisplayFormatAttribute` so that it gives me what I want? Something like

```
[ForecastNumberFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

So I can now directly use `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Amount)` and it gives me 352K, 204M etc. format.

Please note, I do not want to convert this property to string, since I have to do calculations on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to create a read-only calculated property in your model that return the formatted property as string and like this you keep the original format of decimal value.

```
        public string FormattedAmmount
         {
            get
            {
                return Amount.ToForecastNumber()
            }
         }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a wonderful and simple alternative! Sometimes mind is so involved into looking for a complex solution that it skips such options.